# How to integrate EJB with Spring Beans and dealing with Singleton

Tags: spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, singleton

I had a working project with dependency injection and Singleton in clear Java EE:

```
@javax.inject.Singleton
public class SomeSingleton {...}
```

I use it anywhere inside application and I receive the same instance:

```
@Inject SomeSingleton instanceOfSingleton;
```

Lately I had to add Spring module which uses my ***SomeSingleton*** class. Spring needs the instance to be manually produced by @Bean annotation:

```
@Bean
public SomeSingleton someSingleton(){
    return new SomeSingleton();
}
```

The problem is that I have two instances of singleton now. How can I fix this?

Comment: which version of Spring?

Answer (score 0):

on one hand, have a singleton to access Spring's ApplicationContext from anywhere, like explained here: http://sujitpal.blogspot.com.ar/2007/03/accessing-spring-beans-from-legacy-code.html

then use this code snippet:

```
@javax.inject.Singleton
public class SomeSingleton {
    @PostConstruct
    void post() {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplicationContext.get();
        AutowireCapableBeanFactory awcbf = ctx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        awcbf.configureBean(this, "someSingleton");
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you are right, but how to "store 'this' into Spring's ApplicationContext"? After removing @Bean annotation I receive error:

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [example.MyClassName] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Comment: I don't have Spring xml configuration, I have annotation-based one. So I had to receive ApplicationContainer like this:

ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SecurityConfig.class);

After this, I receive infinite number of errors (like if something is looped). If I remove @Bean annotation I still receive error mentioned in my previous comment.

I think It's because Springs configuration works before Java EE Dependency Injection.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a solution but I don't think it is elegant as I have to replace all @Inject annotations. Here it is:

In Spring configuration file (annotation-based):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private void configureApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) {
        SpringApplicationContext.setApplicationContext(context);
    }

    @Bean
    public SomeSingleton someSingleton() {
        return new SomeSingleton();
    }

    //the rest of class code

}
```

My class called SpringApplicationContext (no need to implement ApplicationContextAware):

```
public class SpringApplicationContext {

  private static ApplicationContext CONTEXT;

  public static void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context){
    CONTEXT = context;
  }

  public static Object getBean(String beanName) {
    return CONTEXT.getBean(beanName);
  }

  public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> type) {
      return CONTEXT.getBean(type);
  }

  public static ApplicationContext get() {
      if (CONTEXT == null) {
          throw new RuntimeException();
      }
      return CONTEXT;
  }
}
```

And finally, when I want to use my Singleton, I use this (instead of @Inject):

```
private SomeSingleton someSingleton = SpringApplicationContext.getBean(SomeSingleton.class);
```

I don't know if my solution has any other disadvantages :(